# i am unable to use wifi and bluetooth together properly

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 20.10

I am unable to use bluetooth and wifi both properly together in ubuntu 20.10, when i connect earpods via bluetooth, wifi start misbehaving and when i use wifi , bluetooth start misbehaving.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: What do you mean by "start misbehaving"? What do the logs show? `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` just after "starts misbehaving" to start your investigation. Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Can you use 5Ghz for wifi?  That should help with your issue unless you have plenty of neighbors using 2.4 GHz wifi

Comment: I'm havin an Acer Aspire E1 model and still the same problem. When I connect my headphones to the Bluetooth, the wifi goes either off or is just much slower. Looking for a solution rn.